# MySQL_Erro ao resetar senha root do MySQL_"Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados"

Tags: mysql

Sou iniciante e não sei como corrigir esta questão de conexão do Wordpress ao banco de dados Mysql.

O erro ocorre apos eu resetar a senha do root mysql, o Site caiu e imprime a mensagem:   "Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados"

Answer (score 0):

Procure pelo arquivo `wp-config.php` no diretório raiz do seu site *WordPress* e altere as credenciais de acesso do banco de dados. Deve ser algo parecido com isso.

```
/** Nome do banco de dados para o WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'u694443746_aujev');
/** Nome do usuário */
define('DB_USER', 'u694443746_vaven');
/** Senha */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'zuWupEXEdu');
/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql');
/** Codificação utilizada na criação de tabelas. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
/** O tipo de agrupamento do banco de dados.  Não mude em caso de dúvida. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Utilizei esse guia como referência, para mais detalhes dê uma verificada: https://www.hostinger.com.br/tutoriais/como-corrigir-erro-ao-estabelecer-uma-conexao-de-banco-de-dados-no-wordpress/#gref